# Simple reflection of vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, weird answer

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, reflection

"The linear mapping $\mathcal Z$ denotes reflecting a vector about an axis (line) with direction vector $\mathbf a=(3,4)$ in the plane. Write down the components of $\mathbf y= \mathcal Z\mathbf x$ for an arbitrary $\mathbf x=(x_1,x_2)$ and find a particular vector $\mathbf y$, which gets mapped to $(25,0)$."

Straighforward approach, isn't it: 
Using $(3,4)$ and a vector orthogonal to it as a basis (edit 1: not using a standard basis aka the unit vectors) for $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can write the matrix representation of $\mathcal Z$ as $$
   \mathcal Z_M = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1 & a_2 \\
    a_2 & -a_1  \\
   \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 4 \\
    4 & -3  \\
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix-vector product of $\mathcal Z_M$ with arbitrary vector $\mathbf x$ yields 
$$ \mathbf y = \begin{bmatrix}
    3x_1 + 4x_2 \\
    4x_1 - 3x_2  \\
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
Finding what maps to $(25,0)$ is a matter of solving
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  3&4&25\\
  4&-3&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

which yields $\mathbf y = (3,4)$.

Except it's the wrong result, or it's equivalent to the correct one for reasons I can't see, or it's a technical error for which I've lost an hour of my time:

The author says, for the first part, $\mathbf y = {\frac{1}{25}}(-7x_1+24x_2, 24x_1 + 7x_2)$ and for the second $\mathbf x = \mathcal Z(25,0)=(-7,24)$. Okay, so for the second part he's obviously made an error and mapped $(25,0)$ via the matrix instead of looking what maps to it. However, I can't see how that first part is correct by any stretch of the imagination, except, perhaps by using a different set for the basis. 
Is there a basis which maybe is implicit when finding matrix representations of these simple geometric transformations in linear algebra?

Edit 2: 
So, I basically thought I can construct corresponding matrices for mappings by taking ANY base, not just ${{(1,0), (0,1)}}$ by adjusting the following theorem, which only seems to work for $\mathbf {e_1, e_2} ... \mathbf{e_n}$
[src: http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-LT.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4eck.png)

Comment: Z applied to (3, 4) should be (3, 4), which your Z clearly does not do. Draw a picture and see what happens to (1, 0) and (0, 1) using a bit of trig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $\mathcal Z(3,4)=(3,4)$ and that $\mathcal Z(4,-3)=(-4,3)$. That is, the matrix of $\mathcal Z$ with respect to the basis $\bigl\{(3,4),(4,-3)\}$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. So, the matrix of $\mathcal Z$ with respect to the standard basis is$$\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\4&-3\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\4&-3\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac7{25}&\frac{24}{25}\\\frac{24}{25}&\frac7{25}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Got it. Change of basis formula, of course:

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if $A$ is a reflection, then $A^2=I$. It is not an error to find $A(25,0)$ if you're trying to find what maps to $(25,0)$, because that is the answer! $A(A(25,0))=A^2(25,0)=(25,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The author’s “obvious” error isn’t: every reflection is its own inverse, so $\mathcal Z^{-1}(25,0)=\mathcal Z(25,0).$ I would hope that this property of reflections was mentioned somewhere earlier in the text so that it wasn’t simply pulled out of thin air for this particular exercise.

Now, you *can* construct the matrix of a linear transformation from the images of an arbitrary basis, but you end up with a matrix that’s expressed relative to that basis or, as you did, a matrix that has different bases for its “input” and “output.” For the matrix you constructed, we have $\mathcal Z_M(1,0)=(3,4)$ and $\mathcal Z_m(0,1)=(4,-3)$: the outputs coordinates are expressed relative to the standard basis, but the inputs are relative to your convenient-for-this-reflection basis. We want the standard basis on both sides, so you need to apply a change of basis on the right. The correct matrix of the reflection is therefore $$\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\4&-3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3&-4\\4&3\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac1{25}\begin{bmatrix}-7&24\\24&7\end{bmatrix}.$$